# apt-get update showing errors in kali linux

Tags: kali-linux

I get the following error while using apt-get update in kali linux. How to fix this? My kernel is 5.3.0.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giMKt.jpg)

I have tried to install tor but it shows no valid openPGP found.[Error message(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwsW5.png)
This is my /etc/apt/sources.list file.[sources.list file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4WuE.png)

Comment: Kali is absolutely not for beginners. Start on a more complete unix, switch to kali when you already know what you're doing. Compulsory kali link - [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to remove and reinstall tor.  Or, at the very least, start at step 3 on this list of things to do to install to via Debian.

[Tor's Debian Repo](https://support.torproject.org/apt/tor-deb-repo/)

Comment: I have edited my actual post. Please have a look.

Comment: @PratimKanrar, looks like your `curl` command didn't work because the host deb.torproject.org couldn't be resolved.  Either your DNS provider or your ISP, or whaterver local LAN you're on might be blocking access to that name.